# Custom Action not available after Namespace is added

Tags: salesforce1-app, custom-actions

I am using Custom Action in SF1 for simple redirect purpose. They are working fine till tomorrow. But today, when i add Namespace to my org they suddenly stop working.

I add them in the page layout but still they are not visible in SF1 detail page. I checked and test this in another org and same thing happened there. first they are working but after namespace addition they stopped working(not visible in UI).

Is this a **known bug** or did i missed anything. If anybody have any workaround or any solution please let me know.

Comment: Anybody know the answer